# How to limit the text type axis in "ggplot"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

As seen in the table. How can I show the 20 words with the highest ranked value?

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPcIG.jpg)

```html
<table style="border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0" class="tg"><thead><tr><th style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">ranked</th><th style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">word</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2534</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">ek</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2534</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">kat</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2533</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">tal</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2532</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">siz</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2529</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">iad</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2526</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">plu</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2523</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">iht</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2519</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">gön</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2515</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">ger</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2512</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">cil</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2507</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">kar</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2503</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">bas</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2498</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">kaz</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2493</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">gir</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2487</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">siz</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2482</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">dos</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2476</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">vey</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2469</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">adr</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2461</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">tr</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2454</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">hed</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2445</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">ait</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2435</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">kar</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2424</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">num</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2414</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">akt</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2403</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">adr</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2392</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">faz</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2382</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">tik</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2372</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">tak</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2357</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">kay</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2345</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">aid</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2329</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">gon</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.231</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">sip</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2292</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">gor</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2275</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">bor</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2252</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">ols</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2223</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">hac</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2195</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">hes</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2167</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">bor</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2141</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">ank</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2115</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">yap</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2064</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">deg</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.2004</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">mus</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.1916</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">hem</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.1815</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">mer</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.1695</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">iad</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.1568</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">ban</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.14</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">icr</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.1183</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">aki</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0.0896</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">yas</td></tr><tr><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">0</td><td style="border-color:inherit;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-break:normal">dol</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

```
ggplot(Attribute_Selector,aes(ranked,reorder(word,ranked),group=1),size=5)+
geom_line()+geom_jitter()
```

But ggplot output was like this.

[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EH5LQ.jpg)

Comment: can you provide the sample data, seems like you have attached the ggplot image to your table link.

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you provide at least a sample of your data with `dput(Attribute_Selector)` or if your data is very large `dput(Attribute_Selector[1:20,])`. You can [edit] your question and paste the output. Please surround the output with three backticks (```) for better formatting. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for more info.

Comment: I hope I added the html codes of the table correctly. @campbell Thank you for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr::top_n` this can be achieved via

```
Attribute_Selector %>% 
  top_n(20, ranked) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(ranked, reorder(word, ranked), group=1),size=5)+geom_line()+geom_jitter()
```

Using `mtcars` as exmaple data the following code gives you the top 10 cars by `mpg`:

BTW: I replaced `geom_jitter` with `geom_point`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(cars = row.names(.)) %>% 
  top_n(10, mpg) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(mpg, reorder(cars, mpg), group=1),size=5)+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Worked. Wonderful. Thanks @stefan.

Comment: @Erkan Welcome to SO. If you think that Stefan has answered your question, kindly consider accepting it by ticking the check mark next to his answer!